# FreeBSD 13.2 network on Microsoft's Hypervisor

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualization, hyper-v, freebsd

On the vm I try to connect to the Internet for all needs.

If I ping or try anything it takes forever and no answers are given, at all.

Tried chat GPT and got ideas on updating "/etc/rc.conf" and "/etc/resolv.conf", for instance. None worked. Tried infor online (superuser, as well) and no actual solution happened, either.

ifconfig results (I would type but it's too much text and I can't copy and paste):
[image]

Trying an operation:
[image]

Current resolv.conf:
[image]
Current rc.conf:
[image]

Update: localhost:
[image]

As I am learning FreeBSD now, any help will be appreciated to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Found working status: In VMware Player:
[image]

Does not seem to be a FreeBSD issue but a Windows 11 configuration that VMware has been able to resolve. For me, this solution is fine.

Comment: I tried again (now with: pkg install xorg), this time I have waited (once asked if want to install package management tool I input 'yes') the process and I receive:

Error fetching URL...)
Consider changing PACKAGESITE or installing it from ports: 'ports-mgmt/pkg'

Comment: Also tried now on VMware and the same situation happens. Not sure if it's Windows 11 or FreeBSD's issue when virtualizing.

Comment: Also, during install it connects to the Internet to fetch additional stuff.

Comment: Solution on edit: "Found working status:".